# IF Statement in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have written the folowing condition as per the some online tutorial

```
IF [Nationality]="England" 
   THEN "England" 
ELSEIF [Nationality]="Germany" 
   THEN "Germany" 
ELSE "Others" 
END
```

But continuously getting an error:

> "The formula must be a boolean formula"

What is wrong in the condition?

I have tried other statements too `CASE` and `CONTAINS` for them too same error.

It should accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be trying to filter by condition as pictured below. This field does, indeed, require a boolean condition. It needs to know whether to filter out (False) or keep in (True).

Instead of using this dialog box, try the following:

```
Right Click [Nationality] Field > Click "Create..." > Calculated Field
```

If you put your calculation in the dialog box that pops up, it will work. From there you can filter accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: IF this solved your question entirely THEN please assign the green check mark. :) This will help others in the future who have the same question.

Comment: It’s right next to the up and down arrows on my answer. (It’s actually grey til clicked)

Comment: Hmm. Strange. No. It looks like you voted it up but not hit the check mark. It’s okay though! I’m glad this solution worked for you!

Comment: Got it. Green tick, now?

Comment: Bingo! Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying an IF condition in one of your filters. 
In order for a filter condition to be valid, it should always evaluate to True or False. In your example, you may need to modify your code as below:

```
(IF [Nationality]="England" 
    THEN "England" 
 ELSEIF [Nationality]="Germany" 
     THEN "Germany" 
 ELSE "Others" 
 END) = <Some Column>
```

In the above code you are evaluating your IF condition against some column value.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry buddy, I am not clear on the requirement. Can you help answer following question. Are you trying to add a filter or a calculadora field? The calculation you are testing to put is for getting the % or the nationality?